# DISM.exe works but Get-WindowsOptionalFeature (powershell) fails

Tags: powershell, dism

When using DISM.exe to get Windows optional features using command `dism /Online /Get-Features`, the program exits within 1 second and outputs the right results. But when using the command `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online` in powershell, it stucks for minutes and finally returns nothing or returns an error saying `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature: Class not registered`

```
Windows version: Windows 11 22H2 Professional (22624.1616)
Powershell version: 7.3.4
DISM version: 10.0.22621.1
```

I searched on Bing for information, but it seems that nobody is encountering the same issue. I thought about maybe the server is far away, so I used a proxy but nothing changed.

---

**Added**

I've found a relative issue on GitHub: [PowerShell/PowerShell#13866](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13866)

Comment: That [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13866) is still open.

Comment: This issue is being tracked at [PowerShell/PowerShell#13866](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13866).

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by a corrupted or damaged WMI registry. You can try rebuilding the WMI, but this should be done with caution!

Try these steps:

1. Open elevated command prompt
2. Stop WMI by running `net stop winmgmt`
3. Rename WMI repo by typing `ren C:\Windows\System32\wbem\Repository Repository.old`
4. Restart WMI by running `net start winmgmt`
5. Reboot computer

Try using your PowerShell command again post reboot.

Comment: I've tried and the behavior didn't change.